# Entity Framework: How to disable model compatibility check in Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to create a database initializer that runs all the pending migrations regardless of whether the model is in the correct state or not. I.e. I want the initializer to run all the migrations even if it thinks the model state has changed since generating the migration so that it doesn't through the following error:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled.

Does anyone know how I might get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on automatic migrations. The error says that it cannot get your database in sync with your code because your classes contains changes which are not in any of your code based migrations.

Comment: What are the side effects of turning on automatic migrations? I am concerned that it will try to perform schema changes which I don't want it to do. My solution contains two contexts pointing to the same database (one inheriting another) but resident in two different assemblies and the migrations are split into the two different assemblies (each containing the schema migrations pertaining to the relevant context). Therefore, I don't want to turn on automatic migrations only for it to run some migration code automatically and then trying to run it again when the other context migrates.

Comment: I think I have come up with a solution, will test over the weekend and come back to you on Monday. Thanks for the comments. (Btw, well done on being a familiar face on almost every EF code first question on Stackoverflow! Are you like the Code First Yoda??)